# how to know is the dialog close or not-exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to raise a progress bar for ajax request and prompt it as a modal view, as the request can be submited many times, so I want to check if the dialog is closed by previous rquest (`.dialog("close")` is not drop it), or it is the first request(this dialog is not inited).
there is a function `isOpen()` but is there any function like `isClose()`?

Comment: if there is a function isOpen() you do not need another method I think. `! isOpen()==isClose() `,isn't it ?  In other words `var isClose = !$( ".selector" ).dialog( "isOpen" );`

Answer (score 0):

Use [isOpen](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-isOpen):

```
var dialogClosed = true;
```

Once you open dialog box with some button click event or DOM ready event change dialogClosed to false:

```
dialogClosed = false;
```

And then you can check whether dialog opened or not with the below code:

```
if($("#mydialog").dialog( "isOpen" )){
dialogClosed = false;
}
```

Once you closed the dialog box then change dialogClosed to true:

```
dialogClosed = true;
```

You need to explicitly compare this with true to avoid the dialog being returned as an object. Use one global variable like closed `true` or `false` and then based on the global variable make the decision.